# HTML/CSS/JS Почему параметр slidesPrevColumn все ломает в Swiper Slider

Tags: javascript, html, css, slider, swiper

```js
new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
    slidesPerView: 3,
    slidesPerColumn: 2
  });
```

```html
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.css">
</head>
<body>
 <div class="swiper-container">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 4</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 5</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 6</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 7</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 8</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 9</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 10</div>
    </div>
  </div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>
  </body>
```

Ведь должно выводить 3 блока в ряд и 2 в колонку, из-за одного параметра все ломается.

Comment: Что значит *все ломается*?

Comment: Если я уберу параметр sldiesPerColumn слайдер становится как надо горизонтальным, а при параметре все в колонку. Но должно всего лишь 2 блока выводить в колонку

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно изменить параметр `slidesPerColumnFill`, по умолчанию 'column', вам же нужен 'row'.

```js
new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
    slidesPerView: 3,
    slidesPerColumn: 2,
    slidesPerColumnFill: 'row',
    loop: false
  });
```

```html
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.css">
</head>
<body>
 <div class="swiper-container">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 4</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 5</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 6</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 7</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 8</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 9</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 10</div>
    </div>
  </div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>
  </body>
```